# Can AngularDart route directly to a component?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm using AngularDart and routing. My views are one-liners that contain a single component. I feel the views are not carrying their weight. Can I route directly to a component?

---

**Example:**

```dart
router.root
  ..addRoute(
      name: 'welcome',
      path: '/welcome',
      defaultRoute: true,
      enter: view('views/welcome.html'))
  ..addRoute(
      name: 'camera',
      path: '/camera',
      enter: view('views/camera.html'));
```

**And here's `views/welcome.html`**

```html
<welcome></welcome>
```

**And here's `views/camera.html`**

```html
<camera></camera>
```

---

As you can see, those views are pretty weak. I'm much rather say: "when you enter a view, insert this component"

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to ask the same question, but you were the first! I found a solution, probably not the best one, but at least it works.

I created one html for all routes:

dyn_view.html:

```dart
<div><dynamic-view></dynamic-view></div>
```

and of course a component dynamic-view, which takes actual component tag name from the route provider and dynamically adds to the DOM using the technique described here: [How to add a component programatically in Angular.Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423565/how-to-add-a-component-programatically-in-angular-dart)

dynamic_view.html

```dart
<div></div>
```

dynamic_view.dart

```dart
@NgComponent(
    selector: 'dynamic-view',
    templateUrl: 'view/dynamic_view.html'
)
class DynamicView implements NgShadowRootAware {
  Compiler compiler;
  Injector injector;
  String elementName;

  DynamicView(this.compiler, this.injector, RouteProvider provider) {  
    elementName = provider.parameters["elementName"];
  }

  void onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) {
    DivElement inner = shadowRoot.querySelector("div");
    inner.appendHtml("<$elementName></$elementName>");    
    BlockFactory template = compiler(inner.nodes);
    var block = template(injector);
    inner.replaceWith(block.elements[0]); 
  }
}
```

Now the router. The element name must be passed somehow to the RouteProvider. I was inspired by this post: [Verifying route preconditions prior to loading controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429997/verifying-route-preconditions-prior-to-loading-controller)

```dart
class DynamicViewFactory {
  ViewFactory viewFactory;
  DynamicViewFactory(this.viewFactory);

  call(String elementName) {
     return (RouteEvent event) {
       event.parameters["elementName"] = elementName;
       viewFactory("view/dyn_view.html")(event);
     };
  }
}



class MyRouteInitializer implements RouteInitializer {

  init(Router router, ViewFactory view) {
    DynamicViewFactory dynView = new DynamicViewFactory(view);
    router.root
      ..addRoute(
          name: 'route1',
          path: '/a/:b',
          enter: dynView('componentA'))
      ..addRoute(
          name: 'route2',
          path: '/b/:c',
          enter: dynView('componentB'));
  }
}
```

The above code is slightly modified from what actually I use, so it can have some small bugs, but the general idea is the same.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Cool! I wonder if you can ship this as a pub package so I and others can use it. If you do publish it, please let me know.

Comment: How does your module look? I'm not getting my RouteProvider injected into DynamicView.

Comment: My application is based on Angular tutorial: https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/tree/master/Chapter_06. The module looks like that: '
    class MyModule extends Module {
          MyModule() {  
        type(QueryService);  
        
        type(DynamicView);  
        
        // components  
        type(ApplicationComponent);  
        type(ScreenComponent);  
        ...
    
    
        type(RouteInitializer, implementedBy: MyRouteInitializer);  
        factory(NgRoutingUsePushState,  
            (_) => new NgRoutingUsePushState.value(false));  
      }  
    }'

Comment: The other answer is better now that some features have been added.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be directly supported now

see https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/425

You can route to an inline template (`viewHtml`):

```dart
views.configure({
  'foo': ngRoute(
      path: '/foo',
      viewHtml: '<foo-component></foo-component>')
});
```